# Remove $ from Column after CSV Import

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I am trying to import a CSV file while removing the '$' signs from the first column.

1. Is there any way I can omit the '$' sign with csv.reader?
2. If not, how can I modify aList to remove the $ signs?

> ```
> >>> import csv
> >>> with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
> ...     reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
> ...     for a in reader:
> ...         print a
> ... 
> ['$135.20 ', '2']
> ['$137.20 ', '3']
> ['$139.20 ', '4']
> ['$141.20 ', '5']
> ['$143.20 ', '8']
>
> >>> print(aList) 
> [['$135.20 ', '2'], ['$137.20 ', '3'], ['$139.20 ', '4'], ['$141.20 ', '5'], ['$143.20 ', '8']]
> ```

Ultimately, I would like to prep aList for Numpy functions.

Comment: You can use string replacement to remove the "$". `"$135.20".replace("$", "") == "135.20"` returns `True`. So `aList = [[elem[0].replace("$", ""), elem[1]] for elem in aList]` should work.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the first column and then accumulate the results somewhere else:

```
for col_a, col_b in reader:
    results.append([col_a[1:], col_b])
```

That will remove the first character from the first column and append both columns to another list *results*

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
for a in reader:
    print a[0][1:], a[1]
```

`a[0]` is the first entry in your array, `a[0][1:]` is the first entry starting with the second character.

For example:

```
a="$123"
print a[1:]
# prints 123
```

---

If you want to modify the list itself, try the following:

```
for x in xrange(len(reader)):
    reader[x]=[reader[x][0][1:], reader[x][1]]
```